# Is there a way in macOS to automatically open a URL when another URL is opened?

Tags: macos, url, automator

Is there a way in macOS to automatically open a URL when another URL is opened?

Using Automator, macros, browser plugins or the alike to in the background "listen" for a URL to be opened and when it is open another URL. I want a specific URL (that triggers an application) to open when I open one of several other specific URLs.

Comment: It's technically possible.  I use a program called [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) (free trial, US$10) which replaces the system URL handler with one which displays a dialog box asking me whether I want to actually open this link in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome.  I believe it should not be hard to add a handler, with or without Choosy, to open two URLs or a different URL instead (not sure which of these you want).

Comment: Ok, interesting. I want a specific URL (that triggers an application) to open when I open one of several other specific URLs.

Comment: Instead, or as well? Still not sure.

Comment: A, now I understand. As well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) will let you do what you are asking.  There is an Advanced pane where you can specify custom rules which trigger e.g. on specific URLs, and one of the options is to launch the URL in multiple browsers. (You may have to do something funky to convince Choosy that your other app is one of the "browsers", though.  Maybe you can set up a browser you only use to redirect to your app, Chrome Canary or Opera or something else you don't otherwise wish to use.)